# Book Recommendation on Compiler Construction from OCaml to C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, ocaml

Does anyone know a book on compiler construction that generates C code from OCaml ?

Comment: Imho question for pragrammers, not stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't understand why the question was closed. "We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise". That seems to be exactly what this question is looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You should read Andrew Appel's book "Modern Compiler Implementation in ML". Target is not C, but since C is close to assembly, it should be the same... ;-)